# Foreground service notification overrides other notifications

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have a foreground service which I am running which has a persistent notification, but when my app tries to post other notifications they don't appear. When I disable the channel that the foreground notification posts on, the other notifications start working. Any idea why this would be?

Code for foreground notification:

```
    private static final int FOREGROUND_ID = 99;
....
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "foreground_service";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.primaryColor))
                .build();
        startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID, notification);
```

Code for regular notification:

```
private static final int SUMMARY_ID = 6;
....
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,context.getString(R.string.channel))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mute)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText(text))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.primaryColor))
                .setGroup(MISSED_MESSAGES)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Notification summaryNotification =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, context.getString(R.string.channel))
                        .setContentTitle("Missed Messages")
                        .setContentText("Two new messages")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_mute)
                        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.primaryColor))
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                                .addLine("")
                                .addLine("")
                                .addLine("")
                                .setBigContentTitle("")
                                .setSummaryText("Notifications"))
                        .setGroup(MISSED_MESSAGES)
                        .setGroupSummary(true)
                        .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManager.notify(currentNotificationId, builder.build());
        notificationManager.notify(SUMMARY_ID, summaryNotification);
        currentNotificationId++;
        if (currentNotificationId >= 3) currentNotificationId = 0;
```

Comment: Did you found any solution for this ?

Comment: It was quite a while ago so not entirely sure sorry! But I did fix it eventually. I have a feeling it was something to do with the channels.